# How to prove continuity of this function

Tags: real-analysis, limits, probability-distributions, continuity, improper-integrals

How could I prove that the following function is continuous? Some hints?

Let $f:[0,T]\times]0,\infty[\to\mathbb{R}$ and $T,\sigma, r\in \mathbb{R}$ such that

$f(t,x):=\dfrac{x}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\dfrac{\ln{\frac{x}{k}}+(r+\frac{\sigma^2}{2})(T-t)}{\sigma\sqrt{T-t}}}e^{-\frac{u^2}{2}}du-\times$

$\times -\dfrac{ke^{-r(T-t)}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\dfrac{\ln{\frac{x}{k}}+(r-\frac{\sigma^2}{2})(T-t)}{\sigma\sqrt{T-t}}}e^{-\frac{u^2}{2}}du$,$\hspace{10pt}$

for all $(t,x)\in[0,T[\times]0,\infty[$

$f(t,x):=\max\{0,x-k\}$ $\hspace{10pt}$ eitherwise.

Briefly you can denote

$\alpha(x):=\dfrac{\ln{\frac{x}{k}}+(r+\frac{\sigma^2}{2})(T-t)}{\sigma\sqrt{T-t}}$

$\beta(x):=\dfrac{\ln{\frac{x}{k}}+(r-\frac{\sigma^2}{2})(T-t)}{\sigma\sqrt{T-t}}$

I've met this exercise during my Quantitative Finance course, in the Black & Scholes's pricing formula

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think that if $x<k$ then for all $\epsilon >0$ there esists $\delta>0$ such that $|x-ke^{-r\delta}|<\epsilon$. Note that if $x>k$ this $\delta$ does not exist, more precisely it is negative.
With this fact we can easily prove that in this case the limit is zero.
Eitherwise, if $x>k$ then for all $\epsilon >0$ there esists $\delta>0$ such that $|x-ke^{-r\delta}-x+k|=k|1-e^{-r\delta}|<\epsilon$ and then the continuity is obtained.
I don't think that it is correct, but it is the only idea that I have